# Unable to format a correct JSON for Map

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to pass a JSON but I am not able to give it a correct format due to which its giving error while reading.

```
Map<String, List<PojoClass>> mapObj = (Map<String, List<PojoClass>>) input.getData();
```

Basically fetching data from:

```
protected Map<String, List<Data>> data;

   public Map<String, List<Data>> getdata() {
      return data;
   }
```

In PojoClass lets imagine we have some variables naming name, address, phone etc.

Error:

```
> nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
> deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY
> token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@453fc83a; line: 7,
> column: 27] (through reference chain:
> co.age.ning.mon.dto.PojoClass[\"data\"])"
```

JSON:

```
"data": [
    {
      "key": [
        {
          "id": "id_1",
          "time": "1",
          "code": "xx",
          "val": "ty",
          "op": "false"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@453fc83a; line: 7, column: 27] (through reference chain: co.age.ning.mon.dto.PojoClass[\"address\"])"

Comment: Can you share code what you are doing?

Comment: @Affy please edit the exception into the question.

Comment: You need to include a lot more detail if you want an answer. What is your JSON? Which library are you using? What does your code look like? What error are you getting? What's the full stack trace? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41277871/edit) your post to include this information.

Comment: Have you tried using Jackson to *generate* JSON from such a map? You'll then know what your JSON should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with org.json.JSONObject "JSONObject.wrap([object])"

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Pojo {

public String name;
public String address;
public String contactNo;


JSONObject toJsonObject(){
    return (JSONObject) JSONObject.wrap(this);
}

void convertMap(){
    Map<String,List<Pojo>> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<Pojo> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.add(new Pojo());

    map.put("one",list);
    for(Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()){
        for(Pojo expression : (List<Pojo>) entry.getValue()){
            JSONObject object = expression.toJsonObject();
        }
    }

}
```

}